# How to merge two pandas DataFrames on matching values in a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two DataFrames so they only merge based on matching values in a column 'diagnosis'. I am getting duplicates now from the first dataset and I only need to add columns that matches 0 or 1.

I have tried inner join, outer, left and right.

```
diagnosis   radius_mean texture_mean    perimeter_mean  area_mean   smoothness_mean compactness_mean    concavity_mean  concave points_mean symmetry_mean   ... fractal_dimension_worst thickness   size    shape   adhesion    single  nuclei  chromatin   nucleoli    mitosis
0   1   17.99   10.38   122.80  1001.0  0.11840 0.27760 0.3001  0.1471  0.2419  ... 0.11890 8   10  10  8   7   10.0    9   7   1
1   1   17.99   10.38   122.80  1001.0  0.11840 0.27760 0.3001  0.1471  0.2419  ... 0.11890 5   3   3   3   2   3.0 4   4   1
2   1   17.99   10.38   122.80  1001.0  0.11840 0.27760 0.3001  0.1471  0.2419  ... 0.11890 8   7   5   10  7   9.0 5   5   4
3   1   17.99   10.38   122.80  1001.0  0.11840 0.27760 0.3001  0.1471  0.2419  ... 0.11890 7   4   6   4   6   1.0 4   3   1
4   1   17.99   10.38   122.80  1001.0  0.11840 0.27760 0.3001  0.1471  0.2419  ... 0.11890 10  7   7   6   4   10.0    4   1   2
5   1   17.99   10.38   122.80  1001.0  0.11840 0.27760 0.3001  0.1471  0.2419  ... 0.11890 7   3   2   10  5   10.0    5   4   4
6   1   17.99
```

Comment: I have tried the following code. According to the docs the inner join was supposed to perform inner merge to only combine values in the column_name that match. ```merged_df = pd.merge(new_df_32, new_df_10, on="diagnosis", how='right')
```

Comment: It'll help if you give some examples of what your two dataframes are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reply this way, because longer texts are not so convenient in comments.

What you observe is the typical behavior of `merge` in case both dataframes contain multiple rows for the columns you specify with `on`. If for example you have `m` records in `new_df_32` with `diagnosis=1` and `n` records in `new_df_10`, you will get `n*m` records in your merged dataframe with `diagnosis=1`.

If that is not, what you intended and you want to just add fields from `new_df_10` to `new_df_32`, there are two possibilities:

- Either the join criteria you use is not complete and there are other columns you need to include in the `on` parameter.
- Or join `new_df_32` with an aggregated dataframe produced from `new_df_10`. This would mean, you join all rows of `new_df_32` with a dataframe just containing one row for `diagnosis=0` and one for `diagnosis=1`.

The second case would look like:

```
df10_aggregated= new_df_10.groupby(['diagnosis']).agg('first')
merged_df = pd.merge(new_df_32, df10_aggregated, left_on="diagnosis", right_index=True, how='left')
```

You just would have to elaburate, how you actually need to aggregate the dataframe (which aggregation function for which column) and take into account, that in case of `first` ordering of the dataframe plays a role, so in that case, you might also need to sort it first (using sort_values).

Comment: That definitely helps! df_10 still has duplicates values though, but it doesn't give me 209 thousands of rows in return (only 503 which is much better for my purposes). I was wondering if there is any way to add all the columns from df_10 to df_32, only if they have matching diagnoses (0 or 1) so this way Instead of having 32 columns in df_32 and 10 columns in df_10 I have 42 columns in my merged table (this is for the machine learning part) I want each row to be unique so to speak, with different features (the only common they'll have is diagnosis). Really do appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, I don't understand, why you still have duplicates after aggregating the dataframe. How did you aggregate it? if you just aggregate on `diagnosis` you should get exactly two result columns. If you can aggregate df_10 like this, you should get exactly what you described after merging the two dataframes.

Comment: I mean group on `diagnosis` and apply an aggregate on the rest of the columns. Ups sorry, I wrote `how='right'` above. It should read `how='left'`. But I guess that doesn't change anything, because given your data you could even do an inner join (if both sides only contain 0 and 1 in the column).

Comment: This is the code I used
```df_10_aggregated = dropped_df_10.groupby(['diagnosis']).agg('first')
merged_df = pd.merge(dropped_df_32, df_10_aggregated, left_on="diagnosis", right_index=True, how='inner')```

Left side of my merged table (which is df_32 has all the rows with unique) and right side of the table (new columns that I merged from df_10) has all the same values, meaning I have 200 rows with the same values, the other 200 with another duplicated values. I have tried "how=left, right, inner". Bangin my head againts the wall at this point.

Comment: Your `df_10_aggregated` should only contain as many records as you have distinct values in `diagnosis` in `dropped_df_10`. Can you check that? Are there really 200 distinct values? If there are more rows, than distinct values, then something strange is going on (maybe a bug in pandas, but that still seems unlikely to me).